# Sonar Tomcat installation fails

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, sonarqube

I installed both Sonar and Jenkins on the same Tomcat (7.0.29) version. I followed the instructions, which means that I created the sonarqube database (we are using MySQL), that I built and created the WAR file, and that I deployed that file to Tomcat. I also modified the Tomcat CATALINA_OPTS value to give Tomcat more memory. Jenkins will run, but Sonar will give me a "We're sorry, but something went wrong." error. I checked all of the Tomcat logs but could not find anything useful such as an exception. Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment on Tomcat won't be supported as of next version. Therefore, I recommend you to use the standalone mode instead. Note also that is not recommended to install SonarQube and Jenkins on the same machine. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing#Installing-SonarQubePlatformOverview.

Comment: David, thanks for the answer even though it does not actually solve my problem. I will look into separating Jenkins from Sonar. At least I know I can get Jenkins working and am pretty sure that I can get the standalone version of Sonar working. I had seen this link before - it was how I created the sonarqube database. If I can get this going I will at least know that it will be supported...